# How to translate class not equals (class=!) from jade to html?

Tags: html, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I have problems with writing this code in html. Since `div` already has a class of `form-group` i dont know how to add a class exeption to it inline.

```
 |<% if (!success) { %>
      div.form-group(class!='<%- errfor.name ? "has-error" : "" %>')
        label Your Name:
        input.form-control(type='text', name='name', value!='<%= name %>')
```

Maybe it can be added as an addditional `if` condition? 
The full validation form looks like this:

```
  script(type='text/template', id='tmpl-contact')
form
  div.alerts
    |<% _.each(errors, function(err) { %>
    div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissable
      button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert') &times;
      |<%- err %>
    |<% }); %>
    |<% if (success) { %>
    div.alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable
      button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert') &times;
      | We have received your message. Thank you.
    |<% } %>
  |<% if (!success) { %>
  div.form-group(class!='<%- errfor.name ? "has-error" : "" %>')
    label Your Name:
    input.form-control(type='text', name='name', value!='<%= name %>')
    span.help-block <%- errfor.name %>
  div.form-group(class!='<%- errfor.email ? "has-error" : "" %>')
    label Your Email:
    input.form-control(type='text', name='email', value!='<%= email %>')
    span.help-block <%- errfor.email %>
  div.form-group(class!='<%- errfor.message ? "has-error" : "" %>')
    label Message:
    textarea.form-control(name='message', rows='5') <%= message %>
    span.help-block <%- errfor.message %>
  div.form-group
    button.btn.btn-primary.btn-contact(type='button') Send Message
  |<% } %>
```

The app is running on Node with Backbone.
Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
div.form-group(class!='<%- errfor.name ? "has-error" : "" %>')
```

Reverse your double and sigle quotes:

```
div.form-group(class!="<%- errfor.name ? 'has-error' : '' %>")
```

Then to html will be:

```
<div class="form-group <%- errfor.name ? 'has-error' : '' %>">
```

And will render to ( if `errfor.name` is truthy ):

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
```

---

And as you've used this class on multiple places then simply use a *variable*:

```
script(type='text/template', id='tmpl-contact')
  form
    - var classError = "<%- errfor.name ? 'has-error' : '' %>"
    div.alerts
      |<% _.each(errors, function(err) { %>
      div.alert.alert-danger.alert-dismissable
        button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert') &times;
        |<%- err %>
      |<% }); %>
      |<% if (success) { %>
      div.alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable
        button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert') &times;
        | We have received your message. Thank you.
      |<% } %>
    |<% if (!success) { %>
    div.form-group(class!=classError)
      label Your Name:
      input.form-control(type='text', name='name', value!='<%= name %>')
      span.help-block <%- errfor.name %>
    div.form-group(class!=classError)
      label Your Email:
      input.form-control(type='text', name='email', value!='<%= email %>')
      span.help-block <%- errfor.email %>
    div.form-group(class!=classError)
      label Message:
      textarea.form-control(name='message', rows='5') <%= message %>
      span.help-block <%- errfor.message %>
    div.form-group
      button.btn.btn-primary.btn-contact(type='button') Send Message
    |<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it explained the answer that i asked, but unfortunately didn't solved the problem. Actually this form is not displayed in a browser at all when i'm trying to write it in html and i thought `class!=` was the cause. Probably some kind of bug.

Comment: It appears that `!=` in jade used for unescaping dynamic values inside  `<%...%>` of an attribute, and it is not **not equals**. Now it gets more clear why it will render to `<div class="form-group has-error">`